# Deriving the large $E$ expansion for geodesic boundary time from paper arXiv:2004.01192

Tags: general-relativity, integration, geodesics, ads-cft, asymptotics

In equation (14) of the paper "Holographic flows from CFT to the Kasner universe" https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.01192, they express the boundary time as

$$\label{1} t(0) = -P \int^{r_{\star}}_{0} \frac{\text{sgn}(E) e^{\chi /2}}{f\sqrt{1+ fe^{-\chi}/(r E)^2}} dr\,, \tag{1} $$

where $P$ denotes the principal value, $r_{\star}$ is the near-singularity turning point of the geodesic, $E$ is the geodesic energy, and $f$ and $\chi$ are functions defined in particular regimes. The lower limit, $0$, is the UV boundary. In their equation (19), for large $E$ $(E \to \infty)$ they derive an expansion for $t(0)$:

$$ t(0) = t_{\text{sing}} + \frac{1}{E} + \frac{t_{2}}{E^2} + \frac{\phi_{0}^2}{12E^3}+ \frac{t_{4}}{E^4} + \frac{\phi_{0} \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle + 3 \langle T_{tt} \rangle}{8}\frac{\log E}{E^4} + \frac{t'_{4}}{E^{4/(1-c^2)}}+ \dots  \tag{2} \label{2} $$

There are 3 regimes to consider when deriving the expansion:

1. the UV which is $r\to 0$, with functions here defined as $f = 1 + \frac{ \phi_{0}^2}{4}r^2 + \left( \frac{2 \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle \phi_{0}}{3}-\langle T_{tt} \rangle \right)r^3$ and $\chi = \frac{\phi_{0}^2}{4} r^2 + \frac{2 \phi_{0} \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle}{3}r^3$ .
2. the IR, "Kasner scaling regime" $r\to \infty$ with functions here defined as $f= -f_{1}r^{3+c^2}$, $\chi = 2c^2 \log{r} + \chi_{1}$.
3. the intermediate range between the two, with no defined/specified functions $f$ and $\chi$.

Note, $f_{1}, \chi_{1}, \phi_{0}, \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle, \langle T_{tt} \rangle$ and $c$ are all constants.

I am able to identify some of the terms. For example the $t'_{4}$ term in eqn. (\ref{2}) is found by directly integrating $t(0)$ upon substituting the IR functions of point 2, and evaluating at $r_{\star}$, where

$$r_{\star} = \left( \frac{E^2}{f_{1}e^{-\chi_{1}}}\right)^{1/(1-c^2)}.$$

Note, this $t'_{4}$ term is explicitly given in their paper's equation (20). The $t_{sing}, t_{2}$ and $t_{4}$ terms seem to come from the intermediate range mentioned in point 3 by directly expanding the integrand of eqn. (\ref{1}) in $1/E^2$. Having no specified $f$ and $\chi$ in this region I assume this is why the integrals are not explicitly calculated (i.e. left as  $t_{sing}, t_{2}$ and $t_{4}$ multiplied by their $E$ dependence).

However, I cannot identify the $\log(E)/E^4$ term coming from the UV substitution in the integrand. More specifically, following the paper, the UV functions from point 1 are subbed into eqn. (\ref{1}) and the variable is changed, such that $x = r |E|$. This rescaling lets us expand the integrand as a series in $1/E$. Then, integrating term by term and evaluating at $x=r=0$ (like I evaluated at $r_{\star}$ for the IR case) gives terms 2 and 4 from eqn. (\ref{2}), but not the log term, term 6.

So my question is, is there a particular way I should do this integral? Of course, for a proper definite integral, we would specify an upper bound to integrate up to. Given the functions $f$ and $\chi$ from point 1 were originally constructed from a series expansion around $r=0 \,$, I would assume this upper bound would have to be close, say some small $r_{1}$, such that we can still use these specific $f$ and $\chi$. That would consequently mean the intermediate-range integration would start from $r_{1}$ e.t.c such that the integral is split into three parts: UV ($0 \to r_{1}$), intermediate ($r_{1} \to r_{2}$), IR ($r_{2} \to r_{\star}$). Considering this, I have still been unable to identify this log term, so perhaps I am missing something altogether?

Any ideas are always appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tailored the integrand and checked whether that integrates to this formula?

Comment: Yes I did. More specifically for the UV, after subbing in, rescaling and Taylor expanding to 4th order around $E=\infty$, we get:

$$-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}E} + \frac{x^3 \phi_{0}^2}{8\sqrt{1+x^2}E^3} - \frac{x^4 (\langle T_{tt} \rangle (9 + 6x^2) - 2 \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle (1+x^2)\phi_{0})}{6(1+x^2)^{3/2} E^4} + O\left(\frac{1}{E^5} \right)\,.$$ 

Integrating term by term, and evaluating at the lower limit $x= r E = 0$ (including a minus because of this), we find 
$$\frac{1}{E} + \frac{\phi_{0}^2}{12 E^3}\,,$$ 
but no desired log term.

Comment: Ah. Well, I hoped that this might solve it. Sorry, can't really help any more without investing way too much time :/